# Converting org.opencv.core.Point to android.graphics.Point

Tags: android, opencv

I want to put an icon at a particular point on the image bitmap. I got the point where to be icon to be placed by using OenCV. I could understand that `org.opencv.core.Point` is different from that of `android.graphics.Point`. How can I convert `org.opencv.core.Point` to `android.graphics.Point`?

Answer (score 2):

They're not from the same sources (at least, after you leave the `Object` specification), so there's no direct way to convert them. The best you should be able to do is

[after you have an `org.opencv.core.Point` named `point` already]

```
pt = new android.graphics.Point(point.x, point.y);
```

You could make that a return statement instead of an assignment and just make a method somewhere that just returns `android.graphics.Point` objects for you.

Comment: The same thing is which have done. With the opencv I could draw rectangle at the desired place. Then I want to place icon on each corners of the rectangle. So when I create the android point whith opencv's xy value,icons are not placed in the desired location.

Comment: Could you give more details on what kind of objects or functions you are working with? If you're passing an android.graphics.Point object to a rectangle-generation function that expected an org.opencv.core.Point object... you shouldn't even be able to do that in the first place. But both these objects are functionally just wrappers for the storage of a coordinate point. The real answer is that if your function accepts an OpenCV coordinate point correctly, you should be using an OpenCV coordinate point.