# error: incompatible types: org.opencv.core.Point cannot be converted to android.graphics.Point

Tags: java, opencv, android

I am new to `OpenCV`.

I was wondering how could I convert `org.opencv.core.Point` to `android.graphics.Point`.

This is my code :

```
Point size = new Point();     
display.getSize(size);

double mobile_width = size.x;
double mobile_height = size.y;
```

I received an error message.

```
error: incompatible types: org.opencv.core.Point cannot be converted to android.graphics.Point
display.getSize(size);
```

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/17749789/8035260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this :

```
android.graphics.Point size = new android.graphics.Point();     
display.getSize(size);

double mobile_width = size.x;
double mobile_height = size.y;
```

Read this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point